# SQLite show strange signings when none english chars are stored in tables

Tags: ios, ipad, sqlite, hebrew, non-english

Im coding an iPad App heavily using SQLite 3, I'm able to insert data in Hebrew, i downloaded the Data Base to both Mac and Windows and i was able to see the Hebrew content, but when i retrieve it on the iPad i see chars without meaning like you see in the picture attached,i was trying to look for an answer for few days and i cant find an answer, only questions, can anyone help on this?
Im using this code to get the SQLite results and put it in an NSString

```
d.Visit_Date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
d.Visit_Reason = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
d.Visit_Result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
```

[image: In the table on the middle of the page you can see the results]

Comment: Somewhere you're bobbling a string character set conversion.  The alternating characters in the second row suggest that you're treating a UTF16 string as a `char` string.

Comment: Set fonts like Ariel Hebrew etc. don't use system font set etc. Choose font from here.. http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5484

Comment: Changing the font didn't help